# Cannot open or write to database file

Tags: file, permissions

I have a problem, and I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm a retired .Net developer. I have a simple recipe database program on my computer that I wrote for me and my wife to store our recipes. It's a very bare bones program; you can create, edit and delete recipe categories, and create, edit and delete recipes in any category. Very basic; it doesn't even have search or print functionality. It was written in Visual Basic using Visual Studio 19. Its data is stored in a Microsoft Access database.

Today, I was tinkering with the program. I don't know what I did, but now when I run the program, when it tries to access the database, I get the error message "cannot open or write to the file....you need permission to view and write its data." No other process is accessing the database, and the file permissions haven't changed since the last time the program ran successfully. I can access the database using Microsoft Access, but I can't access it with my program.

If anyone can give me any ideas how to fix this issue, I'd be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a message from your application, not from MSAccess or your operating system. What kind of code do you have that deals with reading from this database?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I fixed the problem. I'm embarrassed to admit it was a dumb mistake on my part. In the process of tinkering with the connection string, somehow I managed to delete the database file name, so the connection string had a path name but no file name. So of course when the program tried to open the file, it couldn't.

I guess that's what happens when you try to do a little programming after not having done it for three years.